# Achar o número máximo e mínimo em lista em uma string

Tags: python, lista, tipagem

Tenho a seguinte arquivo:

```
a = '1 0 10 2 3'
```

Quero imprimir o valor mais alto e o mais baixo, para isso usei o `max()` e `min()` mas ele só conta a unidade. Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
a='joao 1 0 10 2 3'
b=a.split()
c=max(b[1:])
print(c)
c=min(b[1:])
print(c)
```

saida:

> ```
> 3
> 0
> ```

saida que eu quero:

> ```
> 10
> 0
> ```

Comment: Deve ser porque a lista esta como `string` você vai ter que fazer algo do tipo `b = list(map(int, b))` para converter para `int`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que você está comparando *strings* e não números, então quando compara "10" com "3" o primeiro é menor, porque análise é feita caractere por caractere, então a comparação é o caractere "1" com o caractere "3", e claro que "3" é maior. Isto não dá certo, e para funcionar como quer terá que fazer conversão das *strings* em `int`s.

Mas tem um problema, você não pode garantir que todos os itens podem ser convertidos. Você terá que tratar a exceção que será gerada transformando o texto em inteiro, por isso o código fica um pouco mais complicado.

```
a = 'joao 1 0 10 2 3'
b = a.split()
c = []
for i in b:
    try:
        c.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(max(c))
print(min(c))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CabsWe). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wbfiezga-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/MaxMinListString.py).

Obviamente que a pergunta não deixa claro o que fazer com as *string*s, eu tive o entendimento que deveria ignorar e não gerar erro, afinal o código não teria utilidade, e não daria o resultado que o AP pediu na pergunta com dados entrados, e considerei que o exemplo citado de entrada é só para facilitar, que poderia ou não ter textos mesmo no meio dos números em qualquer posição.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 6):

O problema é que quando você divide uma *string* você recebe uma lista de *strings*. A função de máximo e mínimo utilizarão a mesma lógica de ordenação para identificar o maior e o menor valor respectivamente.

A questão é que a ordenação de *strings* é feita de forma alfanumérica. Se você possui as *strings* '1', '0', '10', '2' e '3', o valor 3 será o máximo, pois na ordem alfanumérica, o 3 vem depois do 1. Como a comparação é caractere a caractere, o interpretador do Python não trata 10 como inteiro, mas como dois caracteres.

Antes de definir o máximo e mínimo, você precisará converter os valores para numérico:

```
b = [int(n) for n in a.split()]
```

Comment: Eu reabri porque não é duplicata, esta tem uma especificidade, e por causa disto a sua dá erro na forma atual.

Comment: @Maniero seria só trocar o `a.split()` por `a.split()[1:]`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Pra esse caso acho que funciona, mas e se for outra base de dados? E se for número no primeiro, e se tiver outros nomes? Claro, a pergunta não dá critérios do que fazer, mas acho que não deveria dar erro. Aí cai naquela, ou fecha tudo e só abre se a pergunta tem todos detalhes em ordem, ou as respostas sempre correrão riscos de estarem erradas quando descobre-se que a pergunta tinha outros requisitos.

Comment: Só para acrescentar: para esses caso bastaria usar `b = [int(n) for n in a.split() if n.isdigit()]`, dessa maneira só é incluído e convertido strings que contiverem apenas números.